# Can't configurate PEAK PCAN with python

Tags: python, can-bus

I have a problem, I am trying to send can messages (I have PCAN USB) with python (3.1) but won't succeed. Here is my code (main.py):

```
import can

def send_one():
    with can.interface.Bus() as bus:
        #bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='pcan', channel='PCAN_USBBUS1', bitrate=500000)
        msg = can.Message(
            arbitration_id=0x7DF, data=[2, 1, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00], is_extended_id=False
        )
        try:
            bus.send(msg)
            print(f"Message sent on {bus.channel_info}")
        except can.CanError:
            print("Message NOT sent")
send_one()
```

And here is error messages:

```
Exception: The PEAK-driver couldn't be found!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    send_one()
  File "main.py", line 4, in send_one
    with can.interface.Bus() as bus:
  File "interface.py", line 120, in __new__
    bus = cls(channel, *args, **kwargs)
  File "pcan.py", line 220, in __init__
    raise ValueError("BusState must be Active or Passive")
ValueError: BusState must be Active or Passive
```

I have downloaded PEAK-drivers multiple times and looked the source codes interface.py and pcan.py which are from import can, but I just won't find any solution.

Thank you alreydy!

Comment: What happens, if you follow the error message an actually specify the bus state? E.g. `can.interface.Bus(bustype='pcan', channel='PCAN_USBBUS1', bitrate=500000, state=can.bus.BusState.ACTIVE)`. Apart from that, you can call `can.detect_available_configs()` which will return you all usable interfaces.

Comment: @M.Spiller Specifying the bus state didn't change anything. Still same error messages. Also when detecting available configurations I get message that PEAK-driver couldn't be found.

Comment: So most likely it is not related to python and your code at all? Can you access the interface with the Peak tools, e.g. PCAN-view? Which operating system are you on?

Comment: It might be the case, first time trying this. Yes I can access teh interface with Peak tools, there hasn't been any issues ever. My operating system is Windows 10.